# C++ operator keyword - what is correct syntax for return type?

Tags: c++, syntax

In some existing code, I encountered a class that has following (relevant) lines:

```
...
typedef typename RsrcTraits::Type Type;
...
operator Type()
{
    return m_rsrc;
}
...
```

This code works so . . .

**QUESTION**

Why isn't the return type required in front of keyword `operator` i.e.

```
Type operator()
{
    return m_rsrc;
}
```

Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Well I guess it is a duplicate but the other question wasn't worded in a way for me to be able to find it so I'm gonna leave this question up as a link to the other question.